# Fetching result from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I want to get application_id from table1 where genre_id = 123 and language_code = EN from table2.

Table formats:

**Table 1 :**

export_date
genre_id
application_id

**Table 2 :**

export_date
application_id
language_code

Comment: This is a rudimentary inner join.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT Table1.application_id
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.application_id = Table1.application_id
WHERE Table1.genre_id = 123
AND Table2.language_code = 'EN'
```